# Short story about people who live on a beach, bodies wash up and they have holes in the bodies created by tree roots

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story from around the 80's or 90's, it may have been in an Australian sci fi anthology.

There was this guy who appeared from somewhere (the main character), and this group of people who lived in a beachy sort of area, bodies appear with holes drilled in them which seemed to be created by tree roots. He was investigating some sort of mystery, maybe to do with the bodies, or that was an extra thing that happened while he was investigating the main thing.

It was set in a future where there was no real civilisation there were just this group of people who lived on a beach near mangroves.

Probably very vague, thats about all I remember, thanks

Comment: I was thinking [The Willows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Willows_(story)) but that story is 1) located on the Danube 2) situated around 1900 3) told by passing traveler 3) has no mangroves. (Also very close to "Roadside Picnic", strangely enough)

Comment: Not that one, but sounds interesting